# Defining GUI control event responses using Lua in C++

Tags: c++, gui, lua

I'm using Irrlicht(C++) for a 3D engine, and it has a built in GUI system. The GUI events are something like this:

switch(eventtype)
case button_pressed:
    stuff
case editbox_edited:
    stuff

So far I have begun writing a system that allows me to create the GUIs with Lua scripts. It was very easy to make it so it creates the GUI controls from Lua, but I can not think of a good way to define what should happen when control events occur from Lua too. Here's an example of what I have so far:

Lua:

```
local button = create_button("button label",10,10,100,50)
toggle_control(button,false)
```

C++:

```
static int CreateButton(lua_State* L)
{
 int n = lua_gettop(L);
 core::stringw label = lua_tostring(L,1);
 core::stringw tt((n>=5?lua_tostring(L,6):""));
 int x = lua_tonumber(L,2);
 int y = lua_tonumber(L,3);
 int w = lua_tonumber(L,4);
 int h = lua_tonumber(L,5);
 core::rect r(x,y,x+w,y+h);
 unsigned int id = NextID();
 if(r.isValid())
 {
  gui::IGUIButton* b = device->getGUIEnvironment()->addButton(r,0,0,label.c_str(),tt.c_str());
  cl.insert(ControlPair(id,b));
  lua_pushnumber(L,id);
 }
 else
  lua_pushnumber(L,-1);
 return 1;
}
```

Please ignore the security issues with the code (it is a very early version). So my question is this: What are some good ways of defining the control events from a script interpreter in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Irrlicht, but you could pass a function to the CreateButton that should get called on an event that deals with that button.  You could either pass a string, and do a lookup in the global table for a function with that name at run time, or store a pointer to the lua function itself (which should allow you to do lambdas).

In the past I've done a convention-over-configuation thing, where the game automatically picks up lua functions that fit a callback style.  Eg:

```
createButton("myButton", "label text", 10, 10, 100, 50)

...

function onEvent_myButton(eventParams)
    -- process event
end
```

The game parses the global table, looking for onEvent functions and parsing the function name to see if it matches your new button name.  It hooks that up as a callback.

For some reason our designers found this a more friendly approach.